How do i write my synopsis design constraint(sdc) for a generated clock with a variable frequency?
Here is what I got so far for my SDC:
create_clock -name clk -period 20 -waveform {1.7 19}
This is the part of my verilog code that derives a variable frequency clock(Rx_clk) from a 50MHz clock:
module BaudControl(
    input clk, //50MHz clk
    input [2:0]BC, //baud controller conditions controlled by user
    output reg Rx_clk //Clk with modified BPS
);

    //top 5 most used baud rates
    //50Mhz/bps=clkfrequency/bps
    parameter Baud_9600 = 9'd434; //9600 bauds * 12 = 112500 bps;
    parameter Baud_19200 = 9'd217; //19200 bauds * 12 = 230400 bps;
    parameter Baud_38400 = 9'd109; //38400 bauds * 12 =  460800 bps; with 108=462963bps
    parameter Baud_57600 = 9'd72; //57600 bauds * 12 = 691200 bps; 694444
    parameter Baud_115200 = 9'd36; //115200 bauds * 12 = 1382400 bps;


    reg [8:0] Cntr = 9'd0; //counter register
    reg [8:0] Max_Cntr1; //max counter register
    wire [8:0] Max_Cntr; //net for the max counter
        
    //BC conditions that picks the baud rate 
    assign Max_Cntr=(~BC[2]&~BC[1]&BC[0])?Baud_19200:(~BC[2]&BC[1]&~BC[0])?Baud_38400:(~BC[2]&BC[1]&BC[0])?Baud_57600:(BC[2]&~BC[1]&~BC[0])?Baud_115200:Baud_9600;
    
    always@(posedge clk) begin //loads the value of the max counter
        Max_Cntr1 <= Max_Cntr;
    end
        
    
    always@(posedge clk) begin //updates and increments the counter
        if(Cntr==Max_Cntr1) 
            Cntr <= 9'd0;
        else
            Cntr <= Cntr + 1'b1;
    end
    
    always@(*) begin //toggles Txo_clk
        if(Cntr==Max_Cntr1)
            Rx_clk <= 1'b1;
        else
            Rx_clk <= 1'b0;
    end
    
    
endmodule

Also, if you have a a criticism about my code please mention it. I am a self-taught and would love to get some input.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Community I just edited it. Is it more easier to understand now? I'm just trying to figure out how to write an SDC constraint for a generated clock with a variable frequency which is based on the code i posted.

@toolic I was able to do timing analysis with it. I just found out after reading the replies that the highest frequency is sufficient since my derived clock has lower frequencies. I did update my sdc and so far it got rid of some of the warnings. Also, ill check out CodeReveiw. I have a project im working on that I recently opensourced that I want to get reviewed. Thanks.
create_generated_clock -name Rx_clk -source [get_ports {clk}] [get_pins {clk|combout}]```

When you have variable frequency or switchable clocks, you either have to add design constraints for each different frequency, or go with the highest possible frequency.
Generally speaking if it works at the highest frequency, it should also work at lower frequencies. The routing/cell delays in the FPGA are not a function of frequency but of the hardware itself, so if the setup/hold times are met at the highest frequency, then they will also meet at lower frequencies where you have more time between clock edges.
However I would advise against using a logic generated clock in the design as they are generally high jitter and high skew, and can cause routing problems depending on how the FPGA clock network is designed. You also need to consider clock domain crossing as the new clock is not strictly synchronous (unknown phase relationship).
Instead use your logic to make a clock enable and run things synchronously:
always@(posedge clk)
    if(Rx_clk) begin
        // Only update on the fast clock cycle where the clock enable is high.
        ... do something
    end
end

Here you need to make sure that Rx_clk is high for only a single clock cycle in every Baud Rate clock cycles, which will make the effective clock rate of that always block the baud rate clock frequency, but everything remains using the common synchronous fast clock. Your logic is actually already doing this.
This means that Rx_clk is not actually a clock signal and so does not need any specific SDC constraint (it is an enable, a.k.a. data, signal).

your answer is very insightful! I'm already using the highest clock frequency in my constraints and Im not getting failed timing requirements or negative slacks.
I did not know that logic generated clocks can cause routing problems(I'm going to have to do research on why that is the case). I am going to make minor changes on my code based on your suggestion.
Also, in my current design, I'm avoiding crossing clock domains by using the generated clock as the clocks for my other modules, which I mainly did to reduce the resources used. I'm using an epm240 CPLD so I cant really use PLLs.
